# skip an element in zip

Tags: python

I have two files that are `zipped` with something like the following:

```
for line in zip(open(file1), open(file2)):
    # do-something
```

Unfortunately, now file2 has changed, and there is an additional line at the beginning. Yes, I could get rid of that manually (or with an additional script/program), but since the actual number of involved files is huge, I'd prefer to solve the problem at this level.

So, what I want is something like the following (which would be valid, if open(file) were subscriptable):

```
for line in zip(open(file1), open(file2)[1:]):
    # do-something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
for line in itertools.izip(
    open(file1),
    itertools.islice(open(file2), 1, None)
    ):
    # do something
```

**Edit:** changed from zip to the itertools.izip function.

Comment: I'd also recommend switching to `itertools.izip`, as Alex suggests, to save memory.

Answer (score 4):

`open` gives you an iterator, so it's not "subscriptable" but it can easily be advanced by one (with the `next` builtin in 2.6 or better, the `.next()` method in older Python versions -- I'm assuming 2.6 or better here).

So where you'd like to say:

```
for line in zip(open(file1), open(file2)[1:]):
```

say, instead:

```
f2 = open(file2)
next(f2)
for line in zip(open(file1), f2):
```

or, if you're keen on one-liners:

```
import itertools as it
for line in it.izip(open(file1), it.islice(open(f2), 1, None)):
```

In the latter case, since I'm importing `itertools` anyway, I also take advantage to use its `izip` approach rather than the memory-wasting `zip` built-in;-).

Comment: +1 Actually I am using izip :-) but wanted to keep the question simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = open(file1)
f2 = open(file2)
f2.next()   # Skip the first line of file2 (used to be readline() - thanks, Alex)
for line in zip(f1, f2):
    # do-something
```

Comment: Risky -- it works in the current CPython implementation, but generally mixing iteration on files and calls to other file methods is fragile and not guaranteed, see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.next (in the current CPython implementation, `next` then `readline` breaks, vice versa generally works as of today -- but, why risk it when `next(f2)` is a perfectly solid and guaranteed way to "skip the first line of file2"?!).